# Batch script file get default gateway and ping ip address

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface, command-prompt, ip-address

I am trying to get the default gateway and automatically ping the following ip address 192.168.1.(1-254) then save active or inactive ip address into text file.

From this code, it will scan the default gateway and user have to manually insert the ip address .

Example :

[image]

What im trying to do is scan the default gateway and convert it into a variable so it can be +1 / scan the default gateway and auto start the loop +1

Is it possible to get something like this without insert the IP address?

(default gateway might be different(for example 10.1.180.0) when testing in other network so trying not to set it as static and start the loop )

```
Detected Default Gateway :192.168.1.0 

trying to ping 192.168.1.1

trying to ping 192.168.1.2

trying to ping 192.168.1.3

SET /a defaultipgateway=%count%+1  <-will change the result into 0.1 and stop.
```

Full code :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%a in ('"WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled="True" get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do echo Default IP Gateway : %%~a 

SET count=0
SET /p subnet=Please enter IP address range (for example, 192.168.0) :

:start
SET /a count=%count%+1

ECHO.Trying %subnet%.%count% & ECHO.

ping -n 1 -w 1000 %subnet%.%count% >nul  
IF %errorlevel%==0 echo %subnet%.%count% ACTIVE >> ACTIVE.txt  
IF %errorlevel%==1 echo %subnet%.%count% DOWN >> DOWN.txt

IF %count%==254 goto :eof

GOTO start
```

Comment: So you want to ping the gateway and all addresses in it's range?

Comment: yes, and show the process on the cmd 

default gateway : 192.168.2.0

ping 192.168.1.0
.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this to automatically get the gateway, then ping the range 1 to 254? Seeing that you have both `IPv4` and `IPv6` Gateways, we do this, using `wmic`:

```
@echo off
type nul >up.txt
type nul >down.txt
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%a in ('"wmic nicconfig where IPEnabled="True" get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=^." %%i in ("%%~a") do (
    for /l %%l in (1,1,254) do (
      ping -4 -w 1000 -n 1 %%i.%%j.%%k.%%l | findstr "bytes=32"
     if errorlevel 1 (echo %%i.%%j.%%k.%%l DOWN >> DOWN.txt) else (echo %%i.%%j.%%k.%%l ACTIVE >> ACTIVE.txt)
  )
 )
)
```

I use `findstr` in the ping command to search for `bytes=32` as that is the only indicator that really shows that it got a reply. The reason for that is, if you receive `Destination host unreachable` it still gives a packet loss of 0 and bytes-32 only exists in an actual reply from host.

Tip!! Depending on your network quality and the distance of your PC's on the Lan/Wan and very dependant on how busy your routers and switches are, I would suggest increasing to `-w 1500` instead. Currently, if a device is live and takes longer than 1000ms to respond, it will be sent to the DOWN.txt file. The reason for that is `ICMP` is a diagnostics protocol and does **not** get priority. a Device could be 1 hop away, but if it is very busy handling priority traffic, it will discard your ICMP packets, or cause massive delays in reply.